# Case statement in AWS Redshift

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, dbeaver

I have a table in redshift in which there are some of the fields which are having wrong values for a specific column. I am using the dbeaver tool to run queries on tables in redshift and trying to execute the below query to convert those values to the correct ones.

The query is not throwing either logical or syntactical errors but somehow not getting the correct output yet.

```
select 
CASE
    WHEN (profile$branch$state) IN ('Jaipur') THEN 'rajasthan'
    ELSE profile$branch$state
    END AS state
 FROM profile_detials
WHERE state ILIKE 'jaipur%'
```

I was expecting the output to get 'rajasthan' for the fields have the values as 'Jaipur' but I am still getting the same field values as 'Jaipur'. Is there anything wrong in the query or is there any other syntax for case statements in redshift using dbeaver tool?

The sample input would be as shown below:

| profile$branch$state |
| --- |
| JHARKHAND |
| Jaipur |
| Jammu & Kashmir |
| KARNATAKA |
| Jaipur |
| Orissa |
| Haryana |
| Andhraprasdesh |
| Assam |
| Jaipur |
| Jaipur |

The output that is coming is as shown below:

| state |
| --- |
| rajasthan |
| rajasthan |
| rajasthan |
| rajasthan |
| rajasthan |
| rajasthan |
| rajasthan |
| rajasthan |
| rajasthan |

The sample output I wanted is as shown below:

| state |
| --- |
| JHARKHAND |
| rajasthan |
| Jammu & Kashmir |
| KARNATAKA |
| rajasthan |
| Orissa |
| Haryana |
| Andhraprasdesh |
| Assam |
| rajasthan |
| rajasthan |

Please help.

Comment: What is `profile$branch$state`? Is that the name of a field, or is it some sort of variable?

Comment: Assuming that `profile$branch$state` is a column name, that query is saying: "Get all rows here `state` begins with `jaipur` (case-independent). Then, if `profile$branch$state = 'Jaipur'` (exact match, same case) then replace it with `rajasthan`. If you think it is not behaving correctly, please Edit your question to show us some sample input rows and the output that is appearing, and also the output you are expecting.

Comment: case is an **expression** (they evaluate to a single value). A statement does much more than evaluate to a single value.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I have edited the comment as per your ask. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be with this line:

```
WHERE state ILIKE 'jaipur%'
```

It is saying that **only rows with a State of Jaipur will be included in the output results**. Not that this is referring to the `state` column in the `profile_details` table, *not* the `state` column being generated in the `SELECT` section.

You have not shown us the values in the `state` column, but I suspect whenever `state = 'Jaipur'` then `profile$branch$state` also equals Jaipur. Therefore, the output is showing `rajistan` for every row, since it is only showing rows where the `state` is Jaipur.

Try removing the `WHERE` and you will see a different result.

Comment: The column name of the output that is coming is state only. I mistakenly gave the original table name in the question, sorry about that( I edited the question). And I also tried not using the where condition in the query but I am getting the empty output.

Comment: Please Edit your question and add details (at the bottom) showing your current query.